# StateMachineRuntimePersister Instantiation getting failed because Spring not able to find its dependent bean MongoDbStateMachineRepository

Tags: spring, spring-statemachine

I am new to spring state machines. I am trying to setup state machine for my transaction data and externalise it to mongo database. But i am getting error while creating "StateMachineRuntimePersister" bean.

Error says - **Parameter 0 of method mongoPersist in com.pws.funder.config.PersistConfig required a bean of type 'org.springframework.statemachine.data.mongodb.MongoDbStateMachineRepository' that could not be found**

```
@Configuration
public class PersistConfig {

    @Bean(name="runtime")
    public StateMachineRuntimePersister<WalletGatewayStates, WalletGatewayEvents, UUID> mongoPersist(
             MongoDbStateMachineRepository mongoRepository) {

        return new MongoDbPersistingStateMachineInterceptor<WalletGatewayStates,WalletGatewayEvents,UUID>(mongoRepository);
    }



}
```

Any leads would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Just create interface like this:

```
public interface StateMachineRepository extends MongoDbStateMachineRepository {
}
```

and pass it into `mongoPersist` method.

Spring automatically creates implementation from your repository interface and put this bean in the context.